# Extjs store.getCount() returns 0

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I am trying to load data to store using a json file. But getCount is returning 0.Store and asset.json are in the same folder. What changes do I need to make?

Code for the Model:

```
Ext.define('Nm.model.analysis.Asset', {

     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     requires: [
                'Ext.data.Field'
            ],
     fields: [
              {
                  name: 'assetType',
                  type: 'string'
              },
              {
                  name: 'referenceNo',
                  type: 'string'
              },
                  {
                  name: 'action',
                  type: 'int'
              }
                ]
   });
```

Store I am trying to create :

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     model: 'Nm.model.analysis.Asset',
     proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url : 'asset.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'assets'
        }
        },
        listeners : {
        load : function(store) {
            alert('getcount from listener '+store.getCount());
        }
    }
 });

store.load();
 alert("getcount="+store.getCount());
```

Data in asset.json

```
{
    "assets" : [
                {
                    "assetType" : 'hello',
                    "referenceNo" : 'refNo.1',
                    "action" : 2
                },
                {
                    "assetType" : 'new',
                    "referenceNo" : 'refNo.2'
                }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try: `getTotalCount()`. Check what is the result.

Comment: Can you try changing the url to  '/asset.json'

Comment: Put a break point in the store load function and check whether your store has real data or not.If data is there then it should return the count.

Answer (score 6):

This is valid code. Here is working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/dig). You need to make sure you are calling `store.getCount()` after store has been loaded. store.load is **async!!** ... so doing `store.load();` and then `console.log(store.getCount());` is never going to print > 0. Use declarative or other kind of listener:

```
listeners: {
    load: function(store, records, successful) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Store count A', 'count: ' + store.getCount());
    }
}
```

or

```
store.on('load', function(store, records, successful){
   Ext.Msg.alert('Store count A', 'count: ' + store.getCount());
});

store.load();
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please help me out by running the same code in Siesta. I have tried placing your code in                    StartTest(function(t){ 'your code here' });